# gcloud copy-file as root

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud, file-copying

Today I have create a Debian instance on gce. when I try to copy a file as root I get the following message:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
lost connection
```

On another instance create a few months ago I able to copy-file with root.

The command used is the following:

```
gcloud compute copy-files test/test.txt root@test:/opt/ --project p-id --zone z
```

Comment: It's possible that newer images don't let you log in or copy files directly as root, for security reasons; I'll check up on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For security reasons, newer VM images don't allow direct log-in as root via SSH. You can log in as a non-root user, which will have `sudo` permissions, and set up root-user SSH yourself, though this is **not recommended**. Instead, copy the file over to a non-privileged location and use the `gcloud compute ssh` as a non-root user and the `sudo` command to move the file where it needs to be.